# What is the time complexity of this prime factors algorithm

Tags: javascript, time-complexity

What would be the complexity of this program for finding prime factors of a number. And what are the ways to improve it (Considering only time complexity and not coding standards or space complexity).

Thanks and regards.

See source code :

```js
function primes(n) {
  let primeNumbers = [2];

  if (n < 2) {
    return [];
  } else if (n == 2) {
    return [2];
  }

  for (let i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
    let x = i;
    let j = 0;
    let isPrime = true;
    while (j < primeNumbers.length && primeNumbers[j] <= Math.sqrt(i)) {
      if (x % primeNumbers[j] == 0) {
        isPrime = false;
        break;
      } else {
        j++;
      }
    }
    if (isPrime) {
      primeNumbers.push(x);
    } else {}
  }

  return primeNumbers;
}

function primeFactors(n) {
  let primeNumbers = primes(Math.sqrt(n));
  let i = 0;
  let x = n;

  if (n == 1) {
    return [1];
  }

  if (n == 2) {
    return [2];
  }

  let primeFactors = [];

  while (i < primeNumbers.length) {
  
    while (x % primeNumbers[i] == 0) {
      primeFactors.push(primeNumbers[i])
      x = x / primeNumbers[i];
      if (x == 1) {
        break;
      }
    }
    
    if (x == 1) {
      break;
    }
    
    i++;
  }

  if (x == 1) {} else if (x > 2) {
    primeFactors.push(x);
  }

  return primeFactors;
}

console.log("test : " + primes(122));
```

Comment: What have you tried so far.Please give your good efforts before you ask. What about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Answer (score 0):

This is a slight improvement on the Sieve of Eratosthenes where you terminate the algorithm at step i = sqrt(n). Assuming each step takes constant time, the runtime is O(sqrt(n)).

A better algorithm is the randomized primality algorithm which takes O(log n). 
http://www.cs.ust.hk/mjg_lib/Classes/COMP3711H_Fall14/lectures/Randomized_Primality_Handout.pdf